# maven jetty plugin how to pass system variable

Tags: maven, maven-jetty-plugin, system-variable

How can I pass a system variable to my application using the `jetty:run` command?
Is it possible to pass it like:

```
mvn jetty:run -Dmy.variable=something
```

And use it in my code:

```
String myVariable = System.getProperty("my.variable");
```

Comment: you can do it through run configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mvn jetty:run -DcommandLineName=value

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.10</version>
   <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
                <name>arg1</name>
                <value>${commandLineName}</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

for more details see [this](http://www.dharmeshborad.com/passing-command-line-to-jetty-through-maven-plugin/)